# Hello Have big problem with my app, Heroku deploy H10 eror

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I've build a app using react + nodejs + express + graphql + apollo server /client.

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
```

I don't know what is wrong I have done process.env.PORT and I did every line like in tutorials and its still doesn't work.

Deploy was successful but when I try run application, I get a Application error on heroku.

Does anyone know what can be wrong?

Here is link for code
https://github.com/Andrzej-Marek/Heroku_problem

Comment: what application error do you get

Comment: as you can see in post, H10 erorr from heroku, aplication work normal on localhost

Comment: Have you checked available database connections?

Comment: Thanks guys Ive solve it